# AWS: Check permissions of a Federated Login User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Users login to our AWS account via okta. Hence when i checked, there are no users under IAM.
I have a requirement to check if a certain user has access to a resource in aws. I only get the user's email, and then need to check if that user has access to the resource.

Is there any way i can do this with aws API?

From cloud trail, i got below arn for an user.

```
arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/<Group Name>/abcd.xyz@email.com
```

Tried to query using IAM api, but it wont accept email abcd.xyz@email.com as a valid username.